# Does S3 provide faster retrieval or EBS block storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm creating a rich internet application that will have to quickly retrieve lots of files from servers running on EC2. I need to access all files from any EC2 instance and also have extremely fast retrieval. I'm wondering whether I should use S3 or EBS to store files? I'm inclined on S3, because its accessible from any EC2 instance, but I'm concerned its slower than EBS block storage. Looking for some expert guidance. By the way, I'm new to Amazon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EBS disk mounted to your instance is going to be the faster than s3. However, you can only mount the EBS volume to a single disk. There are some network file system options to get around this.

S3 is object storage and not a block device, it does not fit all use cases.